# How can I find indices of each row of a matrix which has a duplicate in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, duplicates, sparse-matrix, duplicate-data

I want to find the indices all the rows of a matrix which have duplicates. For example

```
A = [1 2 3 4
     1 2 3 4
     2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 4
     6 5 4 3]
```

The vector to be returned would be `[1,2,4]`

A lot of similar questions suggest using the `unique` function, which I've tried but the closest I can get to what I want is:

```
[C, ia, ic] = unique(A, 'rows')

ia = [1 3 5]
m = 5;
setdiff(1:m,ia) = [2,4]
```

But using `unique` I can only extract the 2nd,3rd,4th...etc instance of a row, and I need to also obtain the first. Is there any way I can do this?

NB: It must be a method which doesn't involve looping through the rows, as I'm dealing with large sparse matrices.

Comment: No time now, but first use unique, and then ismember on those that are found as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
[~, ia, ic] = unique(A, 'rows')

setdiff(1:size(A,1), ia( sum(bsxfun(@eq,ic,(1:max(ic))))<=1 ))
```

Comment: Great Q&A! That's a clever way to find rows with more than one occurrence.

Answer (score 4):

Three other possibilities:

1. Sort rows of the matrix (with [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)), detect equal rows (with [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diff.html)) and use indexing to undo the sorting:

   ```
   [As inds] = sortrows(A);
   ind = find(all(diff(As)==0,2));
   result = inds(union(ind,ind+1));
   ```
2. Directly compare every row against every other row (with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)):

   ```
   match = squeeze(all((bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(A, [3 2 1]))), 2));
   result = find(any(match - eye(size(A,1))));
   ```
3. Use [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist.html) with Hamming distance instead of `bsxfun`:

   ```
   match = ~squareform(pdist(A,'hamming'));
   result = find(any(match - eye(size(A,1))));
   ```

The advantage of approaches 2 and 3 is that you additionally get a (symmetric) matrix, `match`, which tells you which row equals which other. For your example,

```
    >> match
    match =
      1     1     0     1     0
      1     1     0     1     0
      0     0     1     0     0
      1     1     0     1     0
      0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: Method 2 looks like a winner

Comment: Method 2 is a nice solution for a small matrix, but I get "Error using permute, ND-sparse arrays are not supported" when attempting on my large matrix. When trying method 1 with a large problem my computer crashed :P

Comment: @MattHarris I've added a new method which is similar to method 2 but avoids generating a large 3D array. It may be more memory-efficient

Comment: `setdiff` with `bsxfun` is probably a winner, but points for 3 other nice solutions.

Comment: @chappjc Hey! Welcome back :-)

Comment: I wouldn't say _back_... I might find another 30 seconds in the next couple of weeks.  :P

Answer (score 3):

One way to identify duplicates is to apply [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) on the `ic` vector from `unique`.  Then, `setdiff` will return the full list if indexes of duplicate rows.

`[~, ia, ic] = unique(A,'rows')

dupRows = setdiff(1:size(A,1),ia(accumarray(ic,1)<=1))`